# Apache Hadoop 2.4 installation failure on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, hadoop

I have tried to install the **Apache Hadoop 2.4** on Ubuntu 14.04 (32 Bit) os all steps went good but when i try to start the Hadoop Services i am getting the Following Error Message :

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I tried to re-compile the native libraries for 32 bit JVM but it also fails 
and When I try to run the `$jps` command it shows only Namenode running.

What should I do now?

Comment: Check your hadoop logs for more details and try to look for warning there, errors or fatal errors and update your question with it. The warning you have here has nothing to do with the hadoop daemons not starting

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, it is just a warning. It wont affect your hadoop functionalities. 
But if you want that to be solved, you have to comple libraries using 32-bit compiler.

Comment: brief your answer to understand others...

Comment: the error is because $HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 was compiled on 32-bit platform. 
To avoid warnings, you need to recompile hadoop sources using 64-bit ( a long process). But, it is a warning and **it won't affect your Hadoop functionalities.**
Reference: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos